# reuse property in my own owl ontology but change domain/range

Tags: dns, range, owl, ontology

i am currently creating my own ontology, which reuses terms of other ontologies.

this brings me to a simple question: i am wondering, if it is it allowed (or: best practice) to reuse existing terms (for instance ObjectProperties) of other vocabularies, but at the same time change their domains and ranges.

in other words: via redefining/redeclaring external ObjectProperties in my own ontology, i am able to reuse them. at the same time i am thinking about changing its domains/ranges to more specific classes than the original domains/ranges. to be more precise i would change the domain/range to subclasses of the original domain/range.

the main reason why i want to do this is that i want to reuse existing terms as much as possible. additionally, i want to narrow the definition of some terms. for instance suppose there is (in an external ontology) the property `ex:hasTimestamp`. the range of this property in the original vocabulary is a very generic class. now, in my own vocabulary, i want to reuse this property and at the same time i want to define its range as the class `time:TemporalEntity` from the time ontology. can i just do this by changing the range definition of the existing `ex:hasTimestamp` property in my ontology, or should i do it differently? e.g. by defining a sub-property of `ex:hasTimestamp`, for instance `my:hasTimestamp` and then providing a more precise range definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring a domain and range of a property in OWL doesn't "restrict what it can be applied to", but rather tells you something about the subject and objects of the property.  For instance, if you have a class hierarchy such that **Human ⊑ Mammal**, then if you have a property **hasAncestor** with domain **Human**, then whenever you have an object property assertion **hasAncestor(x,y)**, you can *infer* that **Human(x)**. But since **Human ⊑ Mammal**, that means that **Mammal(x)**.  So, whenever you see **hasAncestor(x,y)**, you can infer that
**Mammal(x)**.  That means that **Mammal** is *also* a domain of **hasAncestor**.  Properties have more than one domain and range.

This means that if you "redeclare" an ObjectProperty in your ontology, you're not actually "redeclaring" it so much as stating additional things about it.  However, that's typically not something that you should do.  Usually it makes more sense to import the ontology that declares the property you're interested in, declare a *subproperty* of it.  Because of the way that domains and ranges work, you naturally *inherit* domains and ranges of the superproperty, and you can declare additional domains and ranges as you see fit.

For instance, you might declare an ontology about Stack Overflow, and declare a property **answeredUser**, such that **answeredUser(x,y)** when **x** is a user that answered a question by user **y**.  You could import the FOAF vocabulary, and declare that **answeredUser ⊑ foaf:knows**, and add the additional domain and range **StackOverflowUser**.