# Transferring Object Property domain/range to a similar class in another ontology

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

I have these two ontologies with me to merge. [Ontology1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d8adDBRTKxNRt9YEoeNvBoYBSVHtsJWR/view?usp=sharing) and [Ontology2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ofRN56b8OWUKJetsvEBqd_VyyC9o6Slr/view?usp=sharing). After merging class B of two ontologies, the resultant ontology should look like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PlhVHXUgYNig7YV84CNJH5lPYkK4Z_Vj/view?usp=sharing).

I need to merge class B in ontology 1 to class B in ontology 2. When doing this, all the subclasses of B are needed to be transferred to ontology 2. I learned how to do that in this question, [OWL Api, move class from parent A to B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216048/owl-api-move-class-from-parent-a-to-b). The answer does not tell how to move subclass for a separate ontology, but I assume we can do it changing the IRI.

We also have to transfer the object property that goes from class F to class C(assume class C of both ontologies are already matched) to the other ontology(look the range of the object property in the resultant ontology).This question tells how to reuse object properties. But I don't get how it can be related to this problem, [reuse property in my own owl ontology but change domain/range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713793/reuse-property-in-my-own-owl-ontology-but-change-domain-range)
.

Simple question is, can we add a class of another ontology as domain/range for an object property in an ontology using OWL API? If we can, how?

Comment: if you don't want use owl:imports, then you can just add everything from one ontology to another, or you can add some parts from one ontology to another using different OWL-API methods. You can also try [ONT-API](https://github.com/avicomp/ont-api) to work directly with graphs, this is, in my opinion, more convinient, since you can transfer whole resource-tree with anonymous sub-resources (including anything - rdfs:subClassOf, rdfs:range, etc), for example, with help of `Models#getAssociatedStatements(Resource)`

Comment: @ssz, Thanks for the response, what do you mean by, "you can add some parts from one ontology to another using different OWL-API methods"? What methods are you talking about? Could you point an example that my requirement can be satisfied? As I'm new to OWL-API, I don't know much.

Comment: There are javadocs, sources and examples for newcomers. Using `referencingAxioms(...)` or `axioms(...)` accessed from the `OWLOntology` interface you can get list of axioms related to the given object (i.e. object property, i suppose), using the method `add(OWLAxiom)` you can pass just found axioms into the model.

Comment: my question is, why should it not be possible to "transfer" knowledge between both ontologies? In the end, you just have to create and/or copy axioms. You know, everything statement in OWL is an axioms. Just find the axioms from ontology 1 and add them to ontology 2. I don't see any problem here.

Comment: @AKSW, how to add one axiom from one ontology to another? Can we do it by changing the IRI of the relevant axiom?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by changing IRIs. in OWL API you have two `OWLOntology` objects and just take the axiom from one ontology and add it to the other. If you want to have a different namaespace, you have to re-create the axiom with renamed entities

Comment: Sorry if you couldn't get it. I am new to this. That's why. I need to understand how to add one axiom from one ontology to another. Is it ok if the axiom we add have a different namespace than the target ontology? Shouldn't the namespaces of the axiom and the target ontology be the same?

Comment: @AKSW, I still couldn't find a solution for this. Could you clarify? Let's consider an axiom from ontology1 with the IRI prefix 1. The ontology2 have IRI prefix 2. Is it possible to add the axiom with IRI prefix1 to the ontology2 without renaming it with IRI prefix2?

Comment: why not? we have an axiom `ClassAssertion(ns1:s, ns1:A)` in ontology 1. Why should it not be possible to add it to another ontology? you can have arbitrary namespaces for the entities in a single ontology.

Comment: The question is, what do you want to achieve? Clearly, if you have a class lets say "Book" in both ontologies A and B, so `a:Book` and `b:Book` and you want to integrate the data like maybe all axiom about "Book" contained in A to B, then you have to either a) rename the IRI of `a:Book` to `b:Book` in all axioms or b) add some class equivalence axiom which states both classes are the same entity